# Order By desc Not Working Quite correctly

Tags: mysql

Just a quick question. I have a MySQL DB and I run a query like the one below:

```
select * 
from page_load_times 
where build = 1066 and elapsed_time > 4 
order by elapsed_time desc
```

The results include an 11.295 second result yet it is at the bottom of the list and not at the top of the list? Not sure what is going on here.

This is a MySQL DB

Comment: More example data and expected output please. And what DB type is your column?

Comment: your query does not include any order command

Comment: Maybe a decimal is really a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the following worked for me:

```
select * 
from page_load_times 
where build = 1066 and elapsed_time > 4 
order by (elapsed_time + 0) desc
```

Comment: Same as my answer, except you add 0 to elapsed_time in the ORDER BY. Why, if I may ask?

Comment: @Niklas It implicitly converts a string to an integer. Why it's an integer  - well, I guess that's another story

Comment: Oh, I took for granted that elapsed_time was a decimal (why would you have a field like that as a string field?).

Comment: Because that is how it comes over from our test.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `ORDER BY elapsed_time DESC`. That will order the results with the highest elapsed time at the top. Like so:

```
SELECT * FROM page_load_times
WHERE build = 1066 AND elapsed_time > 4
ORDER BY elapsed_time DESC
```